# Widening Data and Changing Columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have managed to delete a little bit of code that did the below task and can't for the life of me figure out how I did it before.

I want to widen the data that has two factors spread over 8 different 'waves'. There are four 'Paper' factors, each with the same four internal factors 'Response'. The output from a previously required function gives the following dataframe:

[[image: The Input Tibble1]

And I would like to make it look like this:

[image: The Dream]

The single column of the first tibble has become the single row of the second tibble.
As you can see, the second tibble has extra factors of `Paper` but these can just be joined row wise.

I really wasn't sure how to attack this, but thought it would be done using the `pivot_wider` function. When I tried

```
times_correct <- times_19 %>%
                  pivot_wider( id_cols = c('Stay/remain in the EU`', 'Leave the EU', 'I would/will not vote', 'Don\'t know'), names_from = eurrefcolnames)
```

I got the error that I can't subset columns that don't exist which makes sense: I need to manually add the correct 'Waves'. I think this is relatively simple, but can't for the life of me figure out how I did it!

Here is the dput of the various tibbles:

```
structure(list(resp = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), .Label = c("Don't Know", "Leave", "Remain", "Will Not Vote"
), class = "factor"), `Stay/remain in the EU` = c(316L, 290L, 
313L, 324L, 338L, 320L, 325L, 335L), `Leave the EU` = c(157L, 
123L, 159L, 154L, 134L, 189L, 187L, 181L), `I would/will not vote` = c(2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 0L), `Don't know` = c(56L, 51L, 55L, 
50L, 57L, 20L, 17L, 0L), Paper = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Times", class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
structure(list(resp = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("Don't Know", 
"Leave", "Remain", "Will Not Vote"), class = "factor"), euRefVoteW1 = c(316L, 
157L, 2L, 56L, 190L, 339L, 4L, 70L, 819L, 79L, 9L, 71L, 1294L, 
1311L, 150L, 523L, 1715L, 2587L, 133L, 630L), euRefVoteW2 = c(290L, 
123L, 3L, 51L, 175L, 282L, 3L, 62L, 777L, 74L, 5L, 62L, 1091L, 
925L, 80L, 371L, 1528L, 2044L, 83L, 517L), euRefVoteW3 = c(313L, 
159L, 3L, 55L, 199L, 334L, 4L, 69L, 835L, 81L, 10L, 57L, 1348L, 
1289L, 139L, 508L, 1766L, 2563L, 156L, 586L), euRefVoteW4 = c(324L, 
154L, 3L, 50L, 215L, 328L, 2L, 61L, 848L, 70L, 10L, 55L, 1397L, 
1267L, 128L, 492L, 1853L, 2494L, 143L, 583L), euRefVoteW6 = c(338L, 
134L, 2L, 57L, 241L, 286L, 2L, 77L, 853L, 68L, 5L, 57L, 1519L, 
1133L, 112L, 520L, 2017L, 2284L, 106L, 667L), euRefVoteW7 = c(320L, 
189L, 2L, 20L, 186L, 384L, 2L, 34L, 832L, 109L, 8L, 34L, 1449L, 
1456L, 87L, 292L, 1906L, 2785L, 55L, 328L), euRefVoteW8 = c(325L, 
187L, 2L, 17L, 187L, 384L, 1L, 34L, 836L, 118L, 5L, 24L, 1462L, 
1522L, 72L, 228L, 1898L, 2852L, 56L, 268L), euRefVoteW9 = c(335L, 
181L, 0L, 0L, 206L, 385L, 0L, 6L, 844L, 102L, 0L, 4L, 1572L, 
1462L, 0L, 21L, 2018L, 2827L, 0L, 20L), Paper = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Times", "Telegraph", "Control", "No_Paper", 
"Rest"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
eurrefcolnames = c('euRefVoteW1','euRefVoteW2', 'euRefVoteW3', 'euRefVoteW4', 'euRefVoteW6',' euRefVoteW7', 'euRefVoteW8',  'euRefVoteW9')
```

EDIT:

Here is the function that create the initial dataframes, is there an edit I could make here perhaps ?

```
tally_reader_number <- function(input_dataframe,newspaper_name) {
  
  #function takes the input of in_all_waves, tallies the number of different eu ref responses using map_df for a given newspaper factor (defined above)
  # and returns a dataframe of responese for each wave with the newspaper factor as a column 
  returned_dataframe <- input_dataframe %>% 
    filter(Paper == newspaper_name) %>%  
    ungroup()  %>%    #function refuses to work without this 
    select(-Paper) %>%
    map_df(table) %>%   # use map_df from the purrr package to "table" each column
    rownames_to_column("response") %>% #convert the rownames to a column named response
    mutate(resp = case_when(response == 1 ~ "Remain", #change the resulting numbers  to the correct responses 
                            response == 2 ~ "Leave", 
                            response ==3 ~ "Will Not Vote", 
                            response == 4 ~ "Don't Know")) %>%  
    select(resp, everything(), -response) %>% #reorder the columns with resp at the front, removing response
    mutate(Paper = newspaper_name)
  returned_dataframe$Paper <- as.factor(returned_dataframe$Paper)
  returned_dataframe$resp <- as.factor(returned_dataframe$resp)
  
  
  returned_dataframe
  
}
```

Comment: In your code `id_cols` there are mismatching quotes

Comment: I wonder if being more explicit in your `pivot_wider()` might clarify what you're trying to do. For example, if after you mutate eurrefcolnames to times_19, is what you're trying to achieve `pivot_wider( id_cols = c("resp", "paper"), names_from = eurrefcolnames, values_from = c('Stay/remain in the EU', 'Leave the EU', 'I would/will not vote', 'Don\'t know'))`?

Comment: @LathanLiou How would I mutate in the `eurrefcolnames`? At present I just have it as a seperate value and when I try your method I get the error ```Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Columns `euRefVoteW1`, `euRefVoteW2`, `euRefVoteW3`, `euRefVoteW4`, `euRefVoteW6`, etc. don't exist.```

Comment: given that you have `eurrefcolnames` as a vector in your global environment, you should be able to do `times_19 %>% mutate(eurrefcolnames = eurrefcolnames)` I would encourage you, however, to minimize the number of variables in your global environment -- it saves on memory and it's tidier!

Comment: It is not clear from the input.  May be `times_19 %>% mutate(eu = eurrefcolnames) %>% pivot_longer(cols = -c(resp, Paper, eu)) %>% select(-name) %>% mutate(rn = rowid(eu)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = eu, values_from = value)`